# Laravel VueJS axios interceptor accessing the vue application

Tags: laravel, authentication, vue.js, axios, interceptor

I've got what's basically the default Vue JS scaffolding that comes with Laravel.

```js
// app.js
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    methods: {
        refreshToken: function() {
            console.log('refreshing the token');
        }
    }
});

// bootstrap.js
window._ = require('lodash');
window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;

try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

This should be familiar to anyone who has used Vue JS with Laravel before.

Now i've tried to add an axios interceptor to handle errors, i've done this below the X-Requested-With header in bootstrap.js

```js
window.axios.interceptors.response.use(
    response => response,
    error => {
        // Show the user a 500 error
        if (status >= 500) {
            console.log({500:error});
        }

        // Handle Session Timeouts
        if (status === 401) {
            console.log({401:error});
            app.refreshToken();
        }

        // Handle Forbidden
        if (status === 403) {
            console.log({403:error});
        }

        return Promise.reject(error)
    }
);
```

The `console.log()` instances work fine to verify that it is working.

However `app.refreshToken()` does not work (and does not give an error either?).

I'm not that surprised since I haven't imported it or anything.

But i've tried this at the top of bootstrap.js: `import app from './app.js';`

And `npm run watch` now throws a warning:

> "export 'default' (imported as 'app') was not found in './app.js'

I modified app.js to change `const app` to be `export const app` but this didn't make any difference.

I'm pretty sure I am just missing some basic understanding of importing and exporting within es6 but unfortunately I can't find anything on Google that will explain it.

Most of my Googling of how to setup this axios interceptor to handle errors has come up with examples using vuex. I really don't want to bring in vuex just to resolve this as I don't want to touch it until i'm sure it's necessary for my particular app and it definitely seems overkill just to be able to follow a tutorial.

How can I call my app.refreshToken() method or access my vue instance within the axios interceptor?

Comment: have you tried adding it on app.js instead of boostrap? ... you'd be making some kind of require import loop otherwise, i think ... Since app calls bootstrap, and then you make bootstrap call app ..

Comment: `export/import` is only used when you have split this up into modules(separate files). It seems like you have everything within `boostrap.js` so this is totally not of any concern here, so you shouldn't be using it. First thing I would do is to simply log out the `app` const to see if it actually holds your `Vue` instance and to rule out any scope issues.

Comment: Everything isn't in `bootstrap.js`, it's in `app.js` which calls `bootstrap.js` at the very start.

And @Erubiel it seems better to not have a bloated app.js file surely? If my interceptor grows app.js could get very, very large.

Answer (score 0):

After

```js
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    methods: {
        refreshToken: function() {
            console.log('refreshing the token');
        }
    }
});
```

Add what the error says it's missing:

> "export 'default' (imported as 'app') was not found in './app.js'

**Just add this:**

```js
export default app;
```

That might solve the compilation problem, as for the call to the function, i have not tested it yet... came with a very similar problem 15 minutes ago..